# Set default style for QGIS Composer Items

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer

When creating a Composer Layout in QGIS, it is useful to add multiple items such as text boxes, shapes and arrows.  Once I have formatted an item (eg an arrow line) is it possible to set it as a default so that subsequent items are created with the same default parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a blank layout, insert one item (e.g. an arrow) and format it to your preference. Then **save this as a template** (and it might be useful to give it a meaningful name like `Arrow`):

[image: Save as template]

Repeat for any other items. Now you can simply add these formatted items from your template by clicking the `Add items from template` folder button next to the `Save as template` icon.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer,

You can set your multiple composer template in a folder (different from the qgis template folder) for example : ".../template_composer_folder"

Then go to preferences>composer (?)> templates composer folder

and add ".../template_composer_folder"

or in french[image: preferences>composer (?)> templates composer folder]

so when you open the Layout Manager you will have all your personnal templates, such as : a0pay_201902, which is a templates located in my personal folder composer templates

[image: layout manager]