# Bad positions of items in saved template

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts, composer-manager, layout-manager

I work with QGIS 3.8

I saved project with print layout which looks good even if I open it again.

Also I saved template of it - but when I create a new layout and open that saved template - it is all wrong. 
Am I missing something? Page size is the same as in the saved project.

Is there any option to fix this?
Or is it possible to save that print layout like a file to copy/paste for another coworkers/computers?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to package your project with plugins like QPackage or QConsolidate3 ? They will help you to easily share your project with your coworkers.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I assume the image you included is the problematic print layout loaded from the template, but since I don't know what the original layout looked like I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Well first there is a picture (or a element) missing in the place of your red cross , you directory have changed. What's your version of QGIS? Are you update? Usually when you ask a question you should put the version to prevent any trouble work with the latest version It's look like you don't have any page in your layout. Try to be more specific in your question if you want the more precise answer

Comment: I have QGIS 3.8. That picture with red cross doesn ´t matter. I´ll load it later. 
My page layout is that white rectangle under the text "Lorem ipsum".
In original print layout was page size A4. I saved it like template. But when I want to make new layout and open that saved template - it looks like in that picture. Even when page size is A4 still. It´s scattered and nothing is in own place (or size) like it was saved in template.

Comment: There was title and under it there were two pictures (that red and green - both the same size) and underneath them was legend on the left side and on the right side there was a small picture with text. But page size from saved template was A4 size and my new layout is A4 too so I don ´t understand why it looks like that.

Comment: How to you save the templates?
How to do you open the templates?

You can check this
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340750/set-default-style-for-qgis-composer-items/340906#340906

So there is a files created when you saved your templates, you should locate it.

Also you can downgrade to 3.4.13 LTR or chek for bug report 

i understand it's not a specific answer, but I don't see, for now, others elements to indicates you.